# How to remove formatting tool for Textarea in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, textarea

I have a textarea where users can input some text but I want to remove the formatting tool on the textarea (see attached image). any idea how I can achieve this please?

This is my code:

```
        <div class="col-10">
            {!! Form::textarea('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>
             trans("lang.restaurant_description_placeholder")  ]) !!}
            <div class="form-text text-muted" >{{ trans("lang.restaurant_description_help") }}</div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you just create a macro for the form and define you textarea there? I do not believe it will have the widget in that case... Look up Larvel custom form macros and see if that works for you.

Comment: I tried the form macro it doesn't work, still showing the textarea with the fomatting tool.